# Cross-reference Permission label to permissionsXXX API Name

Tags: profile, security, guest-user

So, I'm running the SFDC Labs app [Guest User Access Report](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FR6GaUAL) that outlines what permissions a Community Guest User has

The report enumerates permissions where the guest user has `potential risk` given that a specific permission has been granted to the Guest User.

[image]

Now, in most cases, I was able to match the permissions API name to the friendly name available in the UI. But in some cases, I could not find the related permission in the Guest User profile:

- permissionsenablenotifications (*Send Outbound Messages? - can't be disabled*)
- permissionsemailtemplatemanagement (*Nothing like this at all in a guest user profile*)
- permissionsemailadministration (*Nothing like this at all in a guest user profile*)
- permissionsallowuniversalsearch (*Appears to be Knowledge One*)
- permissionsuseweblink ([Appears to be "Allow Access to Customized Actions](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_actions_userperm_rename.htm)")

I found this [excel file via a Spring 14 Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000035XC0AAM) .. the actual Help article I can not find.  This spreadsheet does map labels to API names but is not current.

> Where is the doc on the mapping of permission friendly names to API names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found them using the [Salesforce Inspector Chrome Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) on a profile in my org. I click on `show all data (tooling api)` and see the below which matches up well with what you already got:

1. `permissionsenablenotifications` - **Send Outbound Messages**.
2. `permissionsemailtemplatemanagement` - **Manage Email Templates**
3. `permissionsemailadministration` - **Email Administration**
4. `permissionsallowuniversalsearch`- **Knowledge One**
5. `permissionsuseweblink` - **Allow Access to Customized Actions**

[image]

I pulled all the Permissions from the profile/salesforce inspector into an excel sheet and uploaded it to my google drive so you can see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzTT63GbKlMAOer9oqGgmcYv_kmoctfL/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @KrisGoncalves

Now that I see this, an alternative answer is to use Workbench and do a describe on the profile sobject (albeit, less convenient than seeing it all laid out per the Salesforce Inspector)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link to salesforce Permissionset object. ctrl+f required permission name.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_PermissionSet.htm

Comment: Hi Sagar, link only answers tend to break over time hence the downvotes and your answer has been flagged, it's best to screenshot or copy/paste the relevant parts into your answer as well as including the links to the source material.