# How do I list all Profiles that include "Modify All Data"

Tags: soql, profile, admin

Ideally, I need a list of active users that are assigned to a Profile in which the 'Modify All Data' system permission is checked.

But if I can even, quickly, get a list of just the Profiles with that permission, I can use reports and Excel to do the rest.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm), there's actually a `Permissions*PermissionName*` field for each permission that you can query against. It's using the field's API name.

[image]

In this case, you're interested in Modify all Data so the following SOQL gives you that

```
SELECT ID,Name FROM Profile WHERE PermissionsModifyAllData = TRUE
```

In terms of permission names, you can refer to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291946/cross-reference-permission-label-to-permissionsxxx-api-name) to make sure you're getting the right one based on what you see in the UI as some labels and names might not match.

Comment: Fantastic!   If I can press further, how might I get a list of all of the 'PermissionName' variables that are options in this context?  Can I just assume that they're identical to the screen label with spaces removed?

Comment: Good question, it's actually the API name of the permissions you see in the screen so there are some mismatches and this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291946/cross-reference-permission-label-to-permissionsxxx-api-name) has some ways to make sure you're getting the right one.

Comment: Great...Thanks again!